# How to get an id of a View inside a Fragment

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to get an id of some View in a Fragment from a string, however it doesn't seem to work... Is there a special case for fragments?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View singleplayerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleplayer_tab, container, false);
        setupMap();
        return singleplayerView;
    }

    private void setupRank() {
        TextView view = (TextView) getByStringId("rank0");
        view.setText("hello");
    }



    private final View getByStringId(final String id) {
        return findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getActivi

ty().getPackageName()));
        }
```

So I am trying to set the textView field rank0 in the layout that is used for my fragment... but right now it gets a NUllPointer because it couldnt find the id

Thank you

Comment: you want to get the view from Fragment, which is already in XML. right?

Comment: TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article); and  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false); text view inside R.layout.article_view

Comment: here if somebody help you , you can appreciate it's help with upvote or accept his/her answer , and make motivation for others to help you more

Answer (score 1):

you can define your Layout In your onCreateView() inside Fragments like this:

```
View V = new View(getActivity());
V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container, false);
```

Then

```
TextView SomeField = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.TxtSomeField);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I tried this it didnt give me an error, but it didnt update the view. It still was the same as when it was loaded... any ideas?

Comment: according to your implementation it might be vary! ,try setting your view in onActivityCreated() function : TextView SomeField = (TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.TxtSomeField);

Answer (score 1):

Inside fragment, add getActivity before findViewById:

```
getActivity().findViewById(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
String id;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extra = getArguments();
            id = extra.getString("id", "");
}


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar_details, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(id);
        return view;
    }
```